# Error on postback caused by simultaneous partial and whole postback?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

In an ASP.NET 2.0 project, I've got a form that's used to edit a rather complicated data type.  The form is largely contained in an UpdatePanel, because sections of the form appear and disappear based on selections in dropdowns and radio buttons.  The Save and Cancel buttons are not in the UpdatePanel.

I've designed it so that on `Page_Load` I deserialize the object I'm editing from ViewState and update its properties from the controls on the page.  Then in `OnPreRender` I update the controls with new visibility/values based on the object's properties, and serialize the object back into ViewState.

I'm having a problem where I can consistently get this error briefly:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 0

There is a panel on the page that appears/disappears based on a selection in a dropdown above it.  The dropdown has `AutoPostBack` set to True, but it has no event handler attached; it causes a postback, which means the object is edited in `Page_Load`, and the panel's visibility is updated in `OnPreRender` based on the object's new state.  Also, the dropdown is the default focused control when the page loads.

The repro steps are as follows:

1. Open an object for editing
2. Without clicking anything, press a key on the keyboard to change the dropdown's value.

   - Changing the dropdown with the mouse causes a partial postback and updates the panel's visibility.  Changing with the keyboard doesn't do anything until focus leaves the dropdown.
3. Click the Save button.  The error appears briefly, then the page refreshes and the object is saved successfully.

As noted, the dropdown doesn't post back until it loses focus after being changed with the keyboard.  I think what's happening is that clicking the save button changes focus from the dropdown and starts the postback from the dropdown at the same time as the postback from the Save button.  This is why the error comes up.

So what is the best solution?  I could make that control not be the default focus, but it's still possible to make the error happen through creative use of the tab key.  Is my overall design here unwise?

UPDATE: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271176/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception) seems to be the same issue; their solution is to simply hide the error message.  Is this wise?