# Timer control triiggers updatepanel in 5 seconds and I get a sys.webforms,PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChatUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MetamorphismApp.ChatUserControl" %>

<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" OnTick="timer1_Tick" Interval="5000">
</asp:Timer>
<div id="divChatWindow" class="clChatWindow">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' class="divHeader" ID="lblChatFriend"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image ID="imgFriend" runat="server" CssClass="classFriendImage" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CommandName="Close" CssClass="lbClose"
            OnClick="lbClose_Click">Close</asp:LinkButton></div>
    <div class="chatText" id="idChatText" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSendChat" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpChatMessages">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imageForFriend" runat="server" CssClass="clFriendsImage" ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"fromusername").ToString() %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="chatMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChatMessage" runat="server" Width="142px" CssClass="clChatMessage" EnableViewState="true"
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendChat" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>'
        OnClick="btnSendChat_Click" CssClass="btnSendChat">Send</asp:LinkButton>

</div>
```

I want to use updatepanel triggered by a timer control and after 5 seconds I get a sys.webforms error. I dont wanna populate my repeater using a webservice to be called via jquery and binding the data to the repeater. I want to use the updatepanel for data population. I have read several articles to avoid this error but havent found a solution yet. If I change asyncpostback trigger to postbacktrigger the page does a postback which I dont want to happen. I want to use updatepanel to solve this issue. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to put ScriptManager control on your page.

Comment: ScriptManager is there. The code works fine locally. But it gives an error from the server

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397479.aspx) states that this is just an error response when an error occurs while the request is being processed. What error code are you getting? Have you seen [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271176/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception)?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting error 503 status code. To my surprise if you are facing this error issue on the server then this issue is a server's issue and not your coding issue. Status 503 indicates that the server cannot fulfill the request and it gives this error. Try contacting your hosting provider.